# Conditional formatting of Ed. / Eds. in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

For a certain type of incollection publications (Keyword: B) I would like to use a different name instead of Ed. or Eds. So far I have used \DeclareSourcemap and overwrite to try to get this done, but I have failed. Any idea how to selectively change the Ed. for selective references as in the example below?

Specifically, for publications of the type B I would like the result to read: "In B. Smith (Chair)" instead of "In A. Smith (Ed.)" or
"In B. Smith & B. Meyer (Chairs)" instead of "In A. Smith & A. Meyer (Eds.)"
while it should stay the same for publications of type A.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,
        bibencoding=utf8,
        sortcites=true,
        bibwarn=true,
        firstinits=true,
        isbn=false,
        dashed=false,
        maxbibnames=99,
        babel=other,
        backend=biber,
        hyperref=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{works.bib}

@incollection{articleA,
  author  = {Adams, A.}, 
  title   = {Titel},
  year = {2017},
  booktitle  = {Booktitle},
  editor = {Smith, A.},
  pages   = {201-213},
  keywords = {A},
}

@incollection{articleB,
  author  = {Adams, A.}, 
  title   = {Titel},
  year = {2017},
  booktitle  = {Booktitle},
  editor = {Smith, B.},
  pages   = {201-213},
  keywords = {B},
}

\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{works.bib} 


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=A,title={A}]
\printbibliography[keyword=B,title={B}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to change. What is the output you want? What precisely needs to be changed?

Comment: You are looking for `editortype = {chair}`. But you'll also need to define a new bibliography string for `typechair`. Should this happen automatically for any entry with `keyword = {B}` or can you add `editortype = {chair}` to your bib entries?

Comment: It would be easier to just add `editortype` fields where you need them, but you could work backwards from the `keyword` field with a source map if you had to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the `editortype` field.

You could either add this to your bib entries, e.g.,

```
@incollection{articleB,
  author  = {Adams, A.}, 
  title   = {Title},
  year = {2017},
  booktitle  = {Booktitle},
  editor = {Smith, B.},
  editortype = {chair},
  pages   = {201-213},
  keywords = {B},
}
```

Or you could use a source map to add it to all entries that satisfy `keyword = {B}`, e.g.,

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      % there is probably a better regex than this...
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{(^B$|^B[^\w]|[^\w]B$|,B,)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=editortype, fieldvalue={chair}]
    }
  }
}
```

Either way, you need to define a new bibliography string for `typechair` like this:

```
\NewBibliographyString{typechair}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  typechair = {chair}
}
```

You don't have to define a string for `typechairs` for English (at least) as `biblatex` is smart enough to guess that you just want an *s* on the end for plural.

Here's the full MWE (using the source map option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,
        bibencoding=utf8,
        sortcites=true,
        bibwarn=true,
        firstinits=true,
        isbn=false,
        dashed=false,
        maxbibnames=99,
        babel=other,
        backend=biber,
        hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{articleA,
  author  = {Adams, A.}, 
  title   = {Title},
  year = {2017},
  booktitle  = {Booktitle},
  editor = {Smith, A.},
  pages   = {201-213},
  keywords = {A},
}
@incollection{articleB,
  author  = {Adams, A.}, 
  title   = {Title},
  year = {2017},
  booktitle  = {Booktitle},
  editor = {Smith, B.},
  pages   = {201-213},
  keywords = {B},
}
@incollection{articleC,
  author  = {Adams, A.}, 
  title   = {Title},
  year = {2017},
  booktitle  = {Booktitle},
  editor = {Smith, B. and Meyer, B.},
  pages   = {201-213},
  keywords = {B},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\NewBibliographyString{typechair}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  typechair = {chair}
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      % there is probably a better regex than this...
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{(^B$|^B[^\w]|[^\w]B$|,B,)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=editortype, fieldvalue={chair}]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=A,title={A}]
\printbibliography[keyword=B,title={B}]
\end{document}
```

[image]